# Permission denied when attempting to run the binary from /usr/bin on bootup

Tags: permissions, services

I am writing a service that shall run a binary sitting in `/usr/bin` however on bootup, I see the service kicks in however the binary fails to run due to permission issues.

```
/etc/rc5.d/S99_ServiceFile: line 30: /usr/bin/<binary>: Permission denied
```

I could manually run the binary after running

```
mount / -o rw,remount
$/usr/bin/ chmod a+x <binary>
$/usr/bin ./<binary>
```

but the setting doesn't remain intact forever (after restarting...).

Comment: If I understand you correctly the problem is that `/usr/bin/<binary>` doesn't have the `x` permission at bootup, and after setting this permission the change doesn't persist after reboot? This seems very strange. Which binary it is?

Comment: OK figured out: the permissions of the binary in the source code wasn't kept intact in the result rootfs image. Using fakeroot to copy the file and build it did the trick

Comment: Glad to know that you solved your issue! Could you please post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue really was the permissions of the file weren't maintained as the file was copied hence permission issues. The trick really was to use fakeroot to copy the file and build